# Insufficient storage space problem in LG Optimus with only two apps installed

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, lg-optimus

I got a new phone about a month ago, the LG Optimus. I factory reset it two times. Right now, I only have two apps, Messenger, and the game Siegefall, and already my phone is saying I have insufficient storage space available.

I later found out that Siegefall takes up 432MB which still shouldn't give me the notification and prevent me from downloading any more apps. I don't know what is the reason for this.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: How much free storage is in your internal memory? If you have enough storage space look into this question [Why can't I install apps when I have enough storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25200/why-cant-i-install-apps-when-i-have-enough-storage?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

you could try if there is a option for moving app to external SD card in particular app setting, then move it into external SD card. usually this option is available with micromax and some samsung mobile handsets.

hope this could help