# Insufficient memory to download apps from playstore?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have rooted my device. I am not sure if this is connected or not, but I cannot download apps from the play store: I get a message stating that there is insufficient memory. I have 5.6 GB available on device and 32gb available on the SD Card.

My device is a Galaxy Note 2.

Comment: We get this question frequently here, so please check: [Why am I getting a “Low on Space” warning and having other weird problems?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/16575), [HTC Desire low on internal storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/16575), [How can I deal with “Low on Space” messages on my HTC Incredible?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/16575), [“Cannot download, not enough space” when “Phone Storage” clearly lists enough space](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/16575)

Comment: Btw: It's the *internal storage* (phone storage, nod sdcard) causing this issue. Here you need at least 25 MB free space.