# Low storage notification with 18GB Free!

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I've googled a lot on the issue and came up with many dead ends.

Basically a few hours ago my phone hit 0% and died, and when I got home and plugged it in it throws me a 'storage space running out' message and is EXTREMELY laggy for the first few minutes after booting.

I've tried deleting /data/log as one post suggested, however that folder does not exist.

Here are screenshots of my storage + the error.
https://goo.gl/VPeMn7

Any ideas/advice/suggestions?

My device is a LG G3 (AT&T)
Running Android 5.1.1,
Paranoid Android 5.1
777 Kernal

Comment: Have you tried booting into recovery and wiping dalvik cache and cache?

Comment: As it seems this kernel is unstable for your device, go back to one  working :D I don't really understand users  trying to update to "last version". I, as programmer, do not recommend  my clients to update to "last version", especially a custom one. Why? What should I ask them to update iOS to 9.0 beta? even after 9.0 is official out I still wait a period to see what bugs are revealed by community. As for Android, the same thing I recommend to my clients. Do not jump ahead, wait and see what other say, then jump :D

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Cannot download, not enough space" when "Phone Storage" clearly lists enough space](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/cannot-download-not-enough-space-when-phone-storage-clearly-lists-enough-sp)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupted file in the operating system.

What i would suggest doing is reformatting back to factory settings.

on the phone go to  Apps > Settings > General

Tap Backup & Reset uncheck Back up my Data (if you want a clean slate). Leave it checked if you want to keep your pitures and other documents.

Tap on Factory Data Reset after doing so it should start reformatting

PS. also remember to clear your sdcard cause there might be of a virus
i would also get a antivirus for your phone as well.

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Restart your device, it has helped for me with the same problem!